# Использование модификаторов

Tags: java

Какие модификаторы можно применять к классам в Java?

- `transient`
- `synchronized`
- `native`
- `strictfp`
- `static`
- `final`
- `abstarct`

`final` и `abstract` точно можно, а остальные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В java *модификаторы уровня доступа классов* (**Access Levels**)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**ВАЖНО ЗАПОМНИТЬ!**
[Особенности применения модификаторов в Java](http://www.quizful.net/post/features-of-the-application-of-modifiers-in-java)

Все возможные (на сегодня) вариации использования модификаторов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Особенности применения модификаторов в Java](http://www.quizful.net/post/features-of-the-application-of-modifiers-in-java)

Comment: strictfp можно к любым классам

Comment: @eskelevra спасибо, я поправил таблицу!     strictfp  можно применять действительно со всеми типами классов:  и с внутренними, и  с вложенными, и с внешними, и с абстрактными - вообще с любыми!

Comment: два года прошло ))

Answer (score 0):

Можно применять static для вложенных классов.

Comment: А эти -transient, -synchronized, -native, -strictfp?

Comment: @eskelevra, не быстрее попробовать? ;)

Comment: можно только strictfp

Comment: @eskelevra кстати, не знал, что можно и на классе этот модификатор использовать.